# Entity retrieved cant be replaced with new list

Tags: jsf-2, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1, openjpa, apache-tomee

I have a "strange" behavior with list properties of any kind of entity.

When I try to set a non empty list to a retrieved entity that has a list value with null (because is not fetched) the entity doesn't "reflect" the new non-empty values that I set.

Steps

1. Retrieve any entity (ex. user) from database in an ejb with criteria.
2. The retrieved entity has a OneToMany attribute (roles) by default is lazy that's why if I don't do a fetch (I don't) the list is null
3. Then try to fill the role list with a NON-EMPTY list
4. Here the list that I set has values but the user list has a null in the roles list attribute even though I set it in the step 3

I don't know why this is happening, the only way I could fix this is cloning (using SerializationUtils from Apache commons.lang3) the user entity (see the steps) and with this work, but I don't know why.

1. Retrieve any entity (ex. user) from database in an ejb with criteria.
2. Clone retrieved entity and assign to new one User clonedUser = SerializationUtils.clone(originalRetrivedUser);
3. Then try to fill the role list with a NON-EMPTY list to the clonedUser
4. The list of clonedUser has the correct values

Why do I need to clone? Why can't I set a list to the entity if is not cloned?

I'm using Apache TomEE 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT (with the openjpa version embedded)

```
 ***** ENTITIES *****
    @Entity
    public class User implements Serializable{

       @Id
       private int id;
       private String userName;
       private String password;
       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
       private List<Role> roles;

       //getters and setters..

    }


    @Entity 
    public class Role implements Serializable{

       @Id
       private int id;
       private String roleName;
       @ManyToOne
       @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
       private User user;

      //getters and setters..
    }


   **** EJB INTERFACE LOCAL ****
   @Local
   public interface MyEJBLocal{
      public User getUserWithRoles();
   }


    **** EJB CLASS ****
    @Stateless
    public class MyEJB implements MyEJBLocal{

        @PersistenceContext(unitName ="ANY_NAME")
        private EntityManager em;

      @Override
      public User getUserWithRoles(){

            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
            Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

            cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(User_.userName),"john"));

           User userJohn = em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();  // if I want this work I have to do User userJohn = SerializationUtils.clone(em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult());  [1*]


           //I will create a list of role just for try to set any role the userJohn
          List<Role> roleList = new ArrayList<Role>(2);
          roleList.add(new Role(1,'ADMIN'); //creating and adding role 1
          roleList.add(new Role(2,'DEVELOPER');//creating and adding role 2

         //setting the list of roles created to the user, as you can see the list has 2 values but the value roles of userJohn always is set to null, my setters and getters are correct
         userJohn.setRoles(roleList);

         return userJohn;
      }

    }

    *** MANAGED BEAN ****

    @Named
    public class MyBean implements Serializable{

     @EJB
     private MyEJBLocal ejb;

     public void anyMethod(){
       User user = ejb.getUserWithRoles();
        user.getRoles(); //<---- HERE THE LIST IS ALWAYS NULL but if I use clone in the ejb method (see 1*) I can get the corrected values.

     }
    }
```

I know I can get the values by fetching but I'm trying not to do it.

In the previous example I tried to set the list in the ejb, but if I remove and then put the list in the managed bean I get the same behavior

I just want want to retrieve an entity and add some info but I don't want to persist that new info.

I'm trying to use the detach method but nothing changes.

I don't want to use @Transient because sometimes I need to persist the data, the idea is easy, I want to retrieve an entity then in the managedbean I want to add a new list but no matter what I set to the list (roles) of the entity (user) the list on the entity always set to null like if the list in the entity is protected in some way.